# Degree of the variety of singular points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an irreducible affine variety. The set of singular points of $V$ is a subvariety $W$ of $V$; denote its components by $W_i$. How may we bound $\sum_i \deg(W_i)$ in terms of $\deg(V)$ and $n$?

I am satisfied if we can find a proper subvariety $Z$ of $V$ containing $W$
and a bound for $\sum_i \deg(Z_i)$, where the $Z_i$'s are the components of $Z$.

The one way I can see is what I take to be the obvious one. We can define $V$ by $n+1$ polynomials $F_1,\dotsc,F_{n+1}$ of degree $\leq \deg V$ (by J. Heintz, "Definability and fast quantifier elimination...", MR0716823; thanks to Simon Rydin Myerson for the reference). Then the singular points of $V$ are those in which the Jacobian of $(F_1,\dotsc,F_{n+1})$ has rank less than $n-\dim(V)$.
Since $W$ is a proper subvariety of $V$, there must be some $(n-\dim(V))$-by-$(n-\dim(V))$ minor of the Jacobian that does not vanish on all of $V$. Its intersection with $V$ defines a proper subvariety $Z$ of $V$. By B\'ezout, its degree is at most $\deg(V)^{n+1-\dim(V)}$.

That may be far from tight, however. Can one do better?

Comment: The result that you attribute to Heintz goes back, at least, to Mumford's paper "Varieties defined by quadratic equations".  If you run the analysis in your third paragraph more carefully, then you can bound the total degree of the union of all top-dimensional components $W_i$ of the singular locus, say $\text{dim}(Sing(V))=m$, by $(\text{deg}(V)-1)^{\text{dim}(V)-m}\text{deg}(V)$, cf. Lemma 4.2.5 of the following:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.5296.pdf Will Sawin found examples proving the optimal inequality is within a constant factor of this inequality.

Comment: Ah, nice. Have Will Sawin's examples appeared somewhere?

Comment: Also, can you show me how to run the analysis more carefully? I do not quite see it.

Comment: I do not think his examples have appeared anywhere.  Will Sawin showed me the examples in my office a few weeks ago.  You could e-mail him.  The "careful analysis" is roughly the same as the analysis that you have written except for the following variants: (a) intersect $V$ with a general linear space of codimension $m$ so that the singular locus of the linear section has pure dimension $0$ (and the same degree), and (b) consider linear projections of $V$ to hypersurfaces in ambient space of dimension 1 larger than the dimension of $V$.

Comment: Ah, nice. Also - I was just leafing through Mumford's paper and couldn't spot the result - is it stated in a somewhat different form somewhere, or am I being careless?

Comment: It is the argument in the first paragraph of the proof of Theorem 1.  For every point $p$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$ that is not contained in $V$, there is a linear projection of $V$ to a hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^{r+1}$, $r=\text{dim}(V)$, such that the projection of $p$ is not contained in the hypersurface.  Thus, the defining equation of the hypersurface pulls back to a conical hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^n$ that contains $V$ yet does not contain $p$.  Mumford shows that for every smooth point of $V$, the same argument shows that degree $d$ defining equations "cut out the Zariski tangent space"...

Comment: ...  Thus, the singular locus must be contained in the Jacobian locus of each of these conical degree $d$ polynomials.  This is what leads to the degree bound in Jan Gutt's thesis, Lemma 4.2.5.

Comment: Actually, there's something I don't understand yet. (It's a possible (though hopefully non-existent) gap in the argument that would give us that the singular locus is contained in a proper subvariety of V of degree $\leq (\deg(V)-1) \deg(V)$, not in the argument in Mumford.) How do I know that, when I take a generic projection of V to a hypersurface in A^{r+1}, I am not making some singular point $P$ non-singular? All it might take would be for the direction of the projection to be a direction with respect to which the derivative at $P$ of every one of the equations defining $V$ vanishes.

Comment: In the above, "... would be for the direction of the projection to be a direction" should be "... would be for the projection to kill a direction". Oh, I see now: it is important to carry steps (a) and (b) in your procedure above in that order; if the singular locus has dimension $0$, then we can easily avoid desingularizing any of the (finitely many) singular points.

Comment: I'm not sure of how to use Will Sawin's example to show $\leq (\deg(V)-1) \deg(V)$ is optimal, given that I am only requiring that $Z$ contain the singular locus as a set. It's clear that the scheme-theoretical degree of his intersection is large, but, as a set, the singular locus of $t_1^D+\dotsc+t_{r+1}^D=0$ is just the point at the origin. (If we are actually bounding the degree of the singular locus, as opposed to that of $Z$, small displacements (I'm sure that means *something* over an arbitrary field) should suffice to fix the example.)

Comment: Actually, I'm having new doubts about deg(V) (deg(V)-1). When we intersect with an affine linear space so as to take the dimension of the locus of singular points down to $0$, we are, in effect, replacing our problem by one where the sum of the degrees of the components of maximal dimension of the singular locus is the same. However, the fact that the singular locus in our new problem sits inside a proper subvariety of dim $\leq deg(V) (deg(V)-1)$ doesn't imply the same is true in the original problem.

Comment: As for Heintz: wouldn't the new element there be that $n+1$ polynomials suffice? I don't see a bound in Mumford. (Actually, for our purposes, we do not need such a bound, as the question already makes clear.)

Comment: On second thought, what I do see is how to cover the singular locus by $n-dim(V)$ varieties of degree $\leq deg(V) (deg(V)-1)$. (That is almost as good for my purposes, but is it optimal?) Here is how. Skip step (a). If $dim(V)<n-1$, project $\mathbb{A}^n$ (and $V$ within it) down one dimension in a generic direction. The points $P$ that are "desingularized" in the process are such that the partial derivatives in that direction of all of the finitely many equations of degree $\deg(V)$ defining $V$ vanish. That can't  be the case for all points on $V$...

Comment: ... or else the direction wouldn't be generic. So, there is a polynomial of degree $V$ s.t. its partial derivative in that direction does not vanish in all of $V$. Its vanishing defines a subvariety of $V$ of total degree $\leq deg(V) (deg(V)-1)$; we set it aside. We repeat this argument until $V$ is of codimension $1$. Then one more subvariety of total dimension $\leq deg(V) (deg(V)-1)$ covers the remaining singular points, as above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit.**  As the OP points out, for his purpose it suffices to take the zero locus of a single (nonzero) partial derivative.  So the OP produces a proper closed subset of $V$ containing the singular locus and having degree bounded by $(\text{deg}(V)-1)\text{deg}(V)$.  Although this is not what the OP asks, there are cases where we need an upper bound on the degree of the singular locus (or at least the union of all components of the singular locus that have the maximum dimension).  This often occurs for bounding the set of "bad characteristic" for some property of schemes over a field of (possibly) finite characteristic.  The answer below gives an upper bound on the degree of the singular locus.

I am just rewriting the proof of Lemma 4.2.5 of the following as one answer.  I learned of this from Fedor Bogomolov.

Jan Gutt 
Hwang–Mok rigidity of cominuscule homogeneous varieties in positive characteristic 
PhD. thesis, 2013 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.5296.pdf

The original statement is for projective varieties, but the result for affine varieties follows by intersecting with affine space (a Zariski open subset of projective space).

**Lemma** [Jan Gutt, 2013 thesis, Lemma 4.2.5] For a purely $r$-dimensional closed subscheme $V$ of projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ with degree $D>1$, if the zero scheme $S$ of the $r^\text{th}$ Fitting ideal of $\Omega_{V/k}$ has dimension $m$, then the corresponding $m$-cycle of $S$ has degree no greater than $D(D-1)^{r-m}$.

**Proof.** When $m$ equals $r$, then this just says that the $m$-dimensional cycle of $S$ has degree no greater than the degree of the $m$-dimensional cycle of $V$.  Thus, without loss of generality, assume that $r>m$.  Also, it suffices to prove the result when $k$ is algebraically closed.  The proof uses Theorem 1.1 of the following.

MR0282975 (44 #209) 
Mumford, David 
Varieties defined by quadratic equations. 1970 Questions on Algebraic Varieties 
 
(C.I.M.E., III Ciclo, Varenna, 1969) pp. 29–100 Edizioni Cremonese, Rome 
http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/1970a--CIME-QuadEqns-DAM.pdf

Mumford proves that the ideal sheaf $I$ of $V$ is generated in degree $d$.  More precisely, the linear system $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_k,I(d))$ of sections $g$ of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ that vanish on $V$ has base locus that equals $V$ set-theoretically and that equals $V$ scheme-theoretically, at least on the dense open subset $V\setminus S$ of $V$.
Thus, the common zero scheme in $V$ of the set of partial derivatives, $\partial g/\partial t$ (for varying homogeneous coordinates $t$) is contained in $S$ set-theoretically, and contains $S$ scheme-theoretically (since the Fitting ideal contains these partial derivatives, locally).

By Bertini’s theorem, for $r-m$ general polynomials $g = (g_1 , \dots , g_{r-m})$ in this linear system, for a general choice of homogeneous coordinates on $P^n_k$ and for a choice $t = (t_1 , \dots , t_{r-m} )$ of $r-m$ of these coordinates, the common zero scheme in $V$ of the $r-m$ partial derivative polynomials $\partial g_i /\partial t_i$ is $m$-dimensional and contains $S$. Since these partial derivatives are global sections of $\mathcal{O}(D − 1)$, the degree bound follows.
**QED**.

**Will Sawin's Examples.**  Let $V$ be a subvariety that spans a linear subspace $\mathbb{P}^{r+1}_k \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ and that equals a degree-$D$ hypersurface in this linear space with defining polynomial $g=t_{m+1}^D + \dots + t_{r+1}^D$.  Assume that the integer $D$ is nonzero in $k$.  The Fitting ideal is precisely defined by $t_{m+1}^{D-1},\dots,t_{r+1}^{D-1}$ and the linear polynomials $t_{r+2},\dots,t_n$.  Thus, the degree equals $(D-1)^{r+1-m}$, which is close to $(D-1)^{r-m}D$.

Comment: Nice. But if you are satisfied with a proper subvariety Z containing the singular points, the same argument gives deg(Z)<=D (D-1), and you don't really need Mumford, right?

Comment: Yes, for your question, it suffices to use a single partial derivative.  In the applications of Jan Gutt, it is important to bound the degree of $S$ (or at least the union of those components of $S$ that have maximum dimension).