# Effective bounds for a Bertini-type result

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, smoothness, symbolic-computation, effective-results, elimination-theory

Suppose $X$ is a projective subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$  of *codimension $r$* over $\mathbb{C}$, defined *set-theoretically* by $r$ homogeneous polynomials $P_1,\dots,P_r$ of degree at most $d$. By Bertini's theorem, for a general $r$-subspace $V\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$, the intersection $X\cap V$ is smooth.

I wonder if there is a nonzero low-degree polynomial whose zero locus contains the set of $V$ for which $X\cap V$ is not smooth.
Formally, is there a nonzero polynomial $Q\in \mathbb{C}[X_{0,0},\dots, X_{r, n}]$ whose degree depends only on $r$ and $d$, such that for an $(r+1)\times  (n+1)$ matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$ representing an $r$-subspace $V$, we have $Q(A)=0$ whenever $X\cap V$ is not smooth?

**Edited:** It seems the polynomial I am asking about is the 1st higher Chow form or tangential Chow form. See [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.15/share/doc/Macaulay2/Resultants/html/_tangential__Chow__Form.html), or Page 104 of *Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants*, by Israel M. Gelfand, Mikhail M. Kapranov and Andrei V. Zelevinsky.

My new question is: what is the degree of this higher Chow form? The original (0th) [Chow form](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ebernd/chowforms.pdf) of a variety $X$ has degree $d:=\deg(X)$ in the Plücker coordinates of the $r$-subspace and is multihomogeneous of degree $(d,\dots,d)$ when expressed as a polynomial in the entries of the matrix representing the $r$-subspace. So I guess the degrees of the higher Chow forms are similarly related to $\deg(X)$. I would be grateful if someone can provide an analysis (or references) that is friendly to non-algebraic-geometers like me.

**Edited again:** I have found the following paper which is directly related to my question:

[The Hurwitz Form of a Projective Variety](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.6703.pdf) by Bernd Sturmfels

So the polynomial I am looking for is called the *Hurwitz form* of $X$ in the above paper. However, an estimation of its degree is given in the paper only for the case that singular locus $X_\mathrm{Sing}$ of $X$ has codimension at least two. In this case, the degree of the Hurwitz form (in Plücker coordinates) is the degree of the dual variety $C^\vee$ to $C$, where $C$ is the intersection of $X$ with a general $(r+1)$-subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and is a smooth curve.

So it seems my question is related to the following question: Suppose $C$ is a reduced (and possibly singular) curve that is the set-theoretic complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^n$ of $r$ homogeneous polynomials of degree at most $d$ and a general $(r+1)$-subspace. Is there an upper bound for the degree of $C^\vee$ depending only on $d$ and $r$? I expect the answer to be yes since $\deg(C)\leq d^r$.

Also, by an argument in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316595/degree-of-the-variety-of-singular-points), $X_\mathrm{Sing}$ is contained in a proper closed subset of $X$ of degree at most $\deg(X)(\deg(X)-1)$, if it helps.

Feel free to assume the base field is $\mathbb{C}$ but I am interested in bounds in positive characteristics too.

Comment: You want $X$ smooth of course.

Comment: @abx Even if $X$ is not smooth, its singular locus $X_\mathrm{Sing}$ has codimension at least $r+1$ so a general $r$-subspace would be disjoint from it, no? But it is not very clear to me if $X_\mathrm{Sing}$ is contained in a hypersurface of $X$ of low degree, depending only on $r$ and $d$.

Comment: No, a complete intersection of $r$ hypersurfaces may very well be singular in codimension 1.

Comment: I mean the codimension is $r+1$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, not in $X$, which is good enough I think? I also realized that $X_\mathrm{Sing}$ is indeed cut out by a low degree polynomial by the Jacobian criterion (Thm 16.19 in Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra). So $X_\mathrm{Sing}$ is contained in a variety of low degree and codimension $r+1$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Then the Chow form of $X_\mathrm{Sing}$ can be used to tell which $r$-subspaces are disjoint from $X_\mathrm{Sing}$.

Comment: On second thought, I am not sure how to use the Jacobian criterion to bound the degree of $X_\mathrm{Sing}$ in terms of $d$ and $r$, given that the polynomials $P_i$ are only set-theoretic generators.